# CSS :after and :before to create spacing for <table> not working properly

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to customize some HTML tags by adding additional attributes to my CSS that will create spacing `:before` and `:after` the next `<html>` content.

I'm not able to succeed with `<table>`, I want a table to produce space before and after it. Please see my picture below for the outcome of based of my CSS below.

```
table:before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}

table,
th,
td:after {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6:after {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}

p:after {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}

p:before {
  content: '\a';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

How can I fix or tweak my CSS for tables to actually produce space (for the top and bottom of the table)

---

[image]

as you see in this image, my CSS is breaking the table header in half by adding a line break after, as well there is no space before.

How can I fix this with my CSS?

Comment: what about setting a margin:2rem 0; on the table tag?

Comment: margins? O.o ...

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas, that seemed to do the trick :).  devsandbox, is there any problem with using margins here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comment worked for you, here is the answer!

Before and after is not the recommended way to create space between elements. Only in few cases and very rarely you re going to need before and after for spacing.

In general the two most common ways to give some distance between elements.

**Margin**

For your case, margin-top would push the element down by 2rems. Margin-bottom would create space between the element and the next. In this space however, you can not do anything (eg. Style it) since it is a fix distance between elements

**Padding**

Padding pushes the content down **BUT** the distance between the elements is a part of the element itself. So if you add a background-color: blue; you will have the space with a blue background as well.

Some visual representation:

```css
.row p {
  margin:0;
}
.div-2 {
  background:orange;
  margin:2rem 0;
}

.div-4 {
  background:blue;
  padding:2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row div-1">
        <p>Irrelevant Item</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row div-2">
        <p>With Margin</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row div-3">
        <p>Irrelevant Item</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row div-4">
        <p>With Padding</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row div-5">
        <p>Irrelevant Item</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped

Best regards